# MySql export only schema without data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have a list of tables in mysql database, no need to export data, How to export the tables into CSV structure without the data in it, just the structure?

Comment: What about the table name? Please give an Expected Results example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by the following query:

**OS(Windows):**

```
SELECT 
TABLE_NAME,
GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
INTO OUTFILE 'D:/tableColumnHeaders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**OS(Linux):**

```
SELECT 
TABLE_NAME,
GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/tableColumnHeaders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**Note:** Put your desired `path` after `INTO OUTFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` is a simple way to reconstruct the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
mysql -e 'show create table dbname.tablename;'
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add some explanation to your code? This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.